# How old is Slartibartfast?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy, douglas-adams

We know that Slartibartfast, as the designer of Norway, must have been involved at the start of the 10-million-year Earth program.

And yet we also know that when Arthur meets him, he has been asleep inside the planet of Magrathea for five million years.

So was he actually (more than) five million years old when he went to sleep? He does describe himself as being "old and tired", but surely not *that* old.

Comment: Age seems to be a hugely special-relative term in the HHGTTG 'verse. Take for instance the [pan-dimensional mice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mice_(hyperintelligent_pan-dimensional_beings)#Mice). They seem to have a life expectancy of several million years. So it could very well be that the Magratheans have a similarly long life (from our perspective). However, it is still a good question how old Slartibartfast was.

Answer (score 1):

According to [This](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cult/hitchhikers/guide/slartibartfast.shtml), He was in stasis for 5 million years before awoken to satisfy the order for a duplicate earth. So he is at least that age.

But the question is further muddled in that he joins CamTim, and thus becomes a time traveler himself. He could have been traveling for many years in between appearances in the narrative. He could be anywhere from 5,000,050 years old to several billion and we would have no way to know.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question. I know he was in stasis for 5 million years, that was in my question. I wanted to know how long he was alive *before* then.