# Hitchhiker's Guide time error

Tags: time-travel, the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

I'll add some quotes from the [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe), as it wouldn't get clearer if I quoted everything from the book. The quotes which I'll take from the book won't have any page number, as it varies from edition to edition.

In *The Restaurant at the End of the Universe*, Zaphod, Trillian, Arthur, Ford and Marvin travel in the black ship

> belonging to the rock band Disaster Area *(Wikipedia)*

back in time:

> "We're plummeting back-ward through time." *(Ford in Chapter 20)*

However, they travel too far back in time:

> "[...] If it is what I think it is, and if it's saying what I think it's saying, then we've already gone too far back into the past. Maybe as much as two million years before our own time." *(Ford in Chapter 20)*

Shortly after that, they end their time travel (so they're now two million years before their own time). They then realize that they should get off the ship and use the teleporter to do that, leaving Marvin behind:

> There is a teleporter on the ship for which the guidance system was never built, as it was never intended to be used, and it also requires somebody to stay on the ship to operate it. Marvin is chosen to stay behind and teleport the others, who have no choice but to go wherever it takes them. *(Wikipedia)*

With Arthur and Ford the following happens:

> The teleporter has meanwhile sent Arthur and Ford to the Golgafrinchan Ark Fleet Ship B, a ship of fools, which crash-lands on prehistoric Earth. *(Wikipedia)*

which makes sense, as they're two million years before their time, so the earth is two million years before it's time as well.

What doesn't make sense however is what happens to Zaphod and Trillian:

> Zaphod and Trillian are returned to the Heart of Gold, which is commandeered by Zarniwoop to complete his mission, to discover who really rules the Universe.

Because this means, that Zaphod and Trillian were teleported into their own time, as Zarniwoop and the Heart of Gold didn't exist two million years before their own time. It's the same with Marvin, who somehow made it off the ship as well (I forgot how and it's not quite relevant), who then was on a different planet, where the Krikkit robots found him and took his leg - once again in the normal time, not two million years ago.

Am I not seeing something which explains this or did Adams simply make a mistake here?

Comment: As I recall, they don't meet up again for at least the rest of the book. So they don't need to be at the same time.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Who / what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I mean Ford and Arthur don't see Zaphod and Trillian again for a long time, plenty of time to do some time travelling and get back to their own time.

Comment: @Daa I can't actually prove it, because indeed quite some time passes, but as far as I recall, Ford and Arthur do travel in time (with the eddy), but Zaphod and Trillian don't - so Ford and Arthur were in a different time than Zaphod and Trillian, which still doesn't make sense, as they were in the same time before the teleport.

Comment: Note though that Adams didn't really ever care much about consistency or continuity; I've [previously pointed out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21463/how-old-is-slartibartfast) that Slartibartfast would have to be 5 million years old for his timeline to make sense. And on Brontitall the birds had to evolve from humanoids within 900 years.